# Devise sign in does not work in rspec tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, devise, signing

just as explaned in title.

Here are my rails helper:

```
  0 ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
  9 
  8 require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
  7 require 'spec_helper'      
  6 require 'rspec/rails'      
  5 require 'capybara/rspec'   
  4 require 'capybara-screenshot/rspec'
  3 require 'capybara-screenshot/minitest'
  2 require 'devise'           
  1 include Capybara::DSL      
11  \
  1 abort("The Rails environment is running in production mode!") if Rails.env.production?
  2 
  3 ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!
  4 
  5 RSpec.configure do |config|
  6   config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures" 
  7   config.include Devise::TestHelpers, :type => :controller
  8   config.extend ControllerMacros, :type => :controller
  9   config.include Capybara::DSL
 10   config.use_transactional_fixtures = true
 11   config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!
 12 end
```

This is my acctual test:

```
    1   require 'rails_helper'
  1
  2 describe DashboardController, type: :controller do
  3
  4   it 'should display chart', js: true do
  5     @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]
  6     member = Fabricate(:member)
  7     member.confirm
  8     domain = Fabricate(:domain, member: member)
  9     Fabricate(:url, domain: domain, url: '/ayoo_lmao', time_spent: 122)
 10     Fabricate(:url, domain: domain, url: '/ayoo_lmao', time_spent: 125)
 11
 12     sign_in :member, member
 13
 14     visit root_path()
 15
 16     binding.pry
 17   end
 18 end
```

so when i run this test, Firefox opens and shows me login page(however i did sign_in alredy). When i manualy try to sign_in trough binding.pry AND visit root_path i get:

```
[2] pry(#<RSpec::ExampleGroups::DashboardController>)> visit root_path
Errno::ECONNREFUSED: Connection refused - connect(2) for "127.0.0.1" port 7055
from /home/karlis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:879:in `initialize'
```

My member_fabricator.rb:

```
  2 Fabricator(:member) do
  1   email 'admin@admin.com'
3     password 'rootroot'
  1   first_name 'Rinholds'
  2   last_name 'Jordan'
  3   expiration Time.local(2015, 6, 21, 15, 13, 0)
  4   start_date Time.local(2015, 4, 21, 15, 13, 0)
  5   role 2
  6 end
```

How does one use sign_in in rspec controller tests?

Thanks you.

Comment: Last Error is not valid because i closed firefox driver, it returns "" when i do visit root_path().

Comment: What does your spec/fabricator/user_fabricator.rb file look like?

Comment: I updated the question with member_fabricator.rb file content.

Comment: The problem is that i cant login beause devise thinks user doesnt exist And it does not( from perspective of view) but in binding.pry Member.all returns fine values.

Comment: Resolved by installing databasecleaner!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Resolved by installing databasecleaner!

Comment: I am facing the same problem, can you please explain your solution. installing gem 'database_cleaner' didn't work for me

Comment: Also do you use the same fabricators as me ? Or a factory girl ?

Comment: I have been using databasecleaner since a long time. but this problem occured recently. has it something to do with the firefox update? moreover, i am using factorygirl

Comment: Honestly i have no idea. All i did, i installed Database Cleaner, Maybe try to reinstall database cleaner ?